# inverse knapsack issue

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve next task:
Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value, determine the knapsack minimal carrying capacity of the given total value.

For Example
Input:

```
item1: w = 3.4, v = 3
item2: w = 0.4, v = 1
total value = 7
```

Output:

We should take:

```
item1 x0, item2 x7
```

And

```
minimal capacity = 0 * 3.4 + 0.4 * 7 = 2.8
total value = 7
```

What recursive formulas should I use for general algorithm using dynamic programming? Can anyone show an example of solving this with tiny input data?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  If so, you should tag it as such.  Also, you will want need to demonstrate some effort on solving this problem.  Please tell us what approaches you have tried and the problems you ran into.

Comment: @VaughnCato, I've searched the web for formulas or examples, but found nothing but "classic" knapsack problem. I know I should minimize function like that F = Sum(Weighti * Counti)[i = 0..n](n - ItemCount) and F2 = Sum(Valuei * Counti)[i = 0..n] should be >= than total_value, but I can't make formulas or an algorithm.

Comment: What is "minimal-carrying-capacity"? Why is it not just not taking any items?

Comment: @missingno minimal-carrying-capacity for given total value. By taking some items, we should obtain or exceed total value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional (maximizing) knapsack algorithm should work fine. Just swap all the occurrences of `max` for `min` and you should be almost there. Another way to see this is using negative costs so minimizing becomes maximizing (you will need to pay special attention to the empty case though).